# How do I find out what a wire is made of?

Tags: material-science

I have a wire that is a steel alloy. I want to know what the alloy components are, because I like that this wire does not work harden and fatigue quickly.

Comment: If you don't have a supplier and part number with some documentation, it will be hard. You will need a reasonable metallurgy lab to perform fairly precise composition analysis and metallography. Many important alloy components are present in sub-atomic-percent levels.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest way to get started on this.

First, use a magnet to determine if the wire is iron-based.

If it is, then try to bend it into a sharp angle. If you can, and if it can be unbent and straightened out again, then it is *dead-soft steel* (or plain iron) containing no residual *cold work* and probably no *alloying agents* like chrome, vanadium, molybdenum, nickel, cobalt, etc.

To verify that it is soft steel or iron with no cold work, take the edge of a metal file and drag it across the wire as if to cut it. If the file teeth dig in readily and put a notch in the wire, it is soft steel or iron. If the file teeth do not dig in but just chatter or buzz against the surface of the wire, then it is *hard-drawn* or *alloy steel* wire.

To verify the original presence of cold work, take a fresh sample of the wire and bend it. Then take another sample, heat it to redness in the flame, then extract it slowly from the flame and allow to cool. Then, try bending it. If it bends much more easily than the first sample did, it was *cold-worked* at the factory.

There are some types of stainless steel (containing chrome and nickel) which are furnished in a dead-soft state. These are corrosion-resistant but are very susceptible to strain-hardening. If the kink you put in the wire by bending it refuses to unbend, you might have some of this. To verify, soak a towel in salt water and fold it around the wire overnight. If there is no rust on the towel next morning, then the wire is probably soft stainless.

Note that the lowest grades of steel on the market are recycled, and contain significant amounts of copper and aluminum as contaminants which embrittle the steel. If it takes many bending cycles to break the wire, then it is free of contaminants, and probably consists of pure iron or very low-carbon steel. If the wire requires just a few cycles of bending to break it, then it is what engineers call "cheap-a**" steel.